# CF Cards for SD722

Tags: cf, cards, for, sd722

Hello,

I have done quite a bit of research on CF cards for the SD722 and am fairly comfortable with my decision to go with the San Disk 8GB. I do want to ask a question just to settle my mind. When choosing a disk, Sound Device recommended that you go with cards that are 40x and greater as far as the speed is concerned.

Is this correct and if not, what speed card do you guys use and what other brands are out there that you might recommend.

Answer (score 2):

I am very happy with San Disk and use the Extreme Pro range (100 MB/s) without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Even if the 722 could record 8 simultaneous tracks at 24bit 192kHz, the incoming data rate would only be 4.39MB/s. This is about half the rate of even the modestly-fast CF cards.

The speed of a CD or SD card is much more important for videographers who are shooting 24-30 images per second, or photographers who are shooting multiple shots in quick succession (e.g., sports photographers).

I use a SanDisk Ultra 8GB with a 30MB/s speed in my SD 702 and I've never had a problem.

Cheers!
~Matt

Comment: +1 on this comment. As I've upgraded from  SLR to SLR, and now have one DSLR that pretty much lives in a video shooting rig, I've taken all my lower-speed CF cards that aren't fast enough for video and they all live in my field recording kit. Zero problems. All SanDisk brand.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the Kingston Elite Pro 8gb 133x in my 744T for years without any problems. In my 788T I go with the Sandisk 16gb 400x cards.